# Como Criar um Auto Incremento no Django que não seja pk

Tags: python, django

Estou criando um sistema de memorando com django e ele esta funcionando direitinho, mas estou precisando colocar um campo de auto-incremento que não seja pk. Eu tenho este campo no meu models.

```
Memo = models.IntegerField()
```

Preciso que ele já receba o valor ou do id ou de um contador, estou usando o python3 e django 11.

Se alguém poder me dar uma luz agradeço!

Comment: Transferir a o valor do id para um campo de um documento é má ideia, pois dessa forma vc estará expondo detelhes do banco desnecessariamente.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Editada
>   Parece que a solução original não funciona, o django (v. 1.11) exige que um campo autofield tenha o parametro `primary_key=True`, uma incorencia, a meu ver, para o que serve o parametro? O jeito é tentar remediar com uma função, veja se funciona, a função pode ser colocada no proprio arquivo `models` ou em um outro arquivo separado (contanto que vc o importe em `models.py`)

```
import datetime
def increment_chamado():
    ultimo = Chamado.objects.all().order_by('id').last()
    if not ultimo:
        return str(datetime.date.today().year) + str(datetime.date.today().month).zfill(2) + '0000'
    ultimo_id = ultimo.chamado_id
    ultimo_int = int(ultimo_id[9:13])
    new_int = ultimo_int+1
    new_id = str(str(datetime.date.today().year)) + str(datetime.date.today().month).zfill(2) + str(new_int).zfill(4)
  return new_id
```

No models o campo que identifica o chamado seria:

```
classe Chamado(models.Model):
    chamado_id = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default = 
        increment_chamado, editable=False)
```

[Baseado em um post de thecstream.org.](http://techstream.org/Web-Development/Custom-Auto-Increment-Field-Django)

> Deste ponto em diante, a resposta "original".

### AutoField

Campo Integer com incremento automatico, Chaves primarias o usam automaticamente. Uma chave primária é automaticamente adicionada ao seu modelo se vc não a especificar.

Se vc adicionar ao seu modelo:

```
incremento = models.AutoField(primary_key=False)
```

Vc estará adicionando um campo do tipo que vc deseja (auto-incremento) ao seu modelo.

### SQN

Só que... Se vc não tiver definido uma PK propria, que não seja `autofield`, quando vc tentar rodar o `migrations` para adicionar o seu campo ao banco, vc receberá a msg:

```
AssertionError: A model can't have more than one AutoField.
```

### Solução

Defina sua propria `PK` sobre um campo que não seja `autofield`

### Sugestão

Se vc não tem um campo que possa garantir que seja `unique` para usar como `PK` faça a `PK`como sendo `uuid` assim:

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

Comment: seguindo a dica do Sidon fiz o import uuid e adicionei as duas linhas,id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
 Memo = models.AutoField(primary_key=False) e agora ele me rotorna o seguinte erro quando tento o migrate ou makemigrations,  SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
ERRORS:
geral.Memo.Memo: (fields.E100) AutoFields must set primary_key=True.

Comment: @MARCELOPEREIRADASILVA, Ok, editei a resposta, veja se a nova solução atende.

Comment: @MARCELOPEREIRADASILVA vc tentou a função após a edição? Funcionou?

Comment: oi Sidon ontem não tive como apareceu umas broncas aqui no trabalho pra resolver estou fazendo agora, utilizando o código que você adicionou

Comment: Sidon cara Muito Obrigado por sua ajuda! você não só me mostrou o caminho pra solucionar meu problema como também colocou setas por todo ele sua resposta foi "show de bola" ou melhor "show de dados" rsrsrs.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o [django-sequence-field](https://github.com/gnrfan/django-sequence-field). Veja u exemplo dele:

```
from sequence_field.fields import SequenceField

# Create your models here.

class TestModel(models.Model):

    sequence = SequenceField(
        key='test.sequence.1',
        template='%Y%m%d%(code)s%NNNNN',
        params={'code':'ABC'},
        auto=True
    )
```

Testando a Model

```
from my_app.models import TestModel

obj = TestModel()
obj.save()

print obj.sequence # 20140703ABC00001

obj = TestModel()
obj.save()

print obj.sequence # 20140703ABC00002
```

**Alternativa**

Você pode fazer essa validação na mão mesmo também:

```
def next_sequence():
    _model = Memorando.objects.filter().order_by('-Memo')[:1]
    if _model.count() > 0:
        return int(_model[0].Memo) + 1
    return 0
```

Comment: Ok Cara, sua resposta é boa, a primeira parte usa um pacote não nativo do django que apenas encapsula, em um pacote, a função sugerida na segunda parte que é copia da minha resposta editada. Pare de negativar minhas respostas cara, o que vc ganha com isso?

Comment: A partir do momento que uma resposta tem uma "solução" que não funciona, e só no final da resposta a pessoa propoe algo que não é uma resposta (como um auto increment usando uuid), eu negativo. Eu não ganho nada, eu perco 1 ponto. A comunidade ganha.

Comment: Estranho não é? não funciona mas foi a resposta aceita.  Acho que vc se apressou em criticar antes de analisar. A comunidade ganharia mais com bom senso.

Comment: A resposta ser aceita é uma coisa, estar certa de acordo com a pergunta é outra coisa. Abraços!

Comment: Cara... Desencana! Sai do meu pé.

Comment: Olá Guilherme IA! Cara também analisei sua resposta e usei a alternativa que você me propôs cara funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado mesmo por sua ajuda agora tenho via visão ampla de como montar o código aqui.